# How to edit text file through iPython Notebook connected to remote server?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm exploring a new workflow for interacting with a remote server and iPython has many attractive properties for session logging and scripting.  The one thing I have not figured out yet is how to do effective text file manipulation on the remote machine.

I'm aware of the `%load` and `%writefile` magic commands, but that's quite awkward for general use.

Is there a way to get `%edit` to work when using Notebook connected to a remote (*nix) server?    Best solution would be an simple editor that opens up in the web browser similar to the panes created by the `command_name?` help viewer.  My search seems to suggest that doesn't exist.  I have found this [PEP](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPEP-18:-Text-Editor-for-the-Notebook) requesting it.

I figure it's probably possible to have `%edit` trigger an X-windows editor to open up on my local machine, but I don't see how to make that happen.  That would be a fine answer if there's a way to do it.

I should also clarify that I'm not generally interested in executing python code in the files, I just want to edit the file.  i.e. `%edit -x` would probably be my general use case.

Comment: There is now a text editor in the notebook - if you click on text files in the dashboard, it should come up with an editor. It's not yet integrated with `%edit`, though.

Comment: That's another alternative to point out @ThomasK.  I don't find that workflow to be any faster than switching over to an open terminal session. The main downsides are: 1) have to switch over to Notebook's "Home" window which does not track the working directory of the iPython session. 2) Contrary to reproducibility, no way to know from the notebook that a file was edited.